# How to pass param from my website -> file excel online -> office add in

Tags: excel, add-in, excel-addins, vba

I'm building an office add-in that helps people learn excel by interacting directly with excel files online. User will access the courses on my website, each course has about 20 - 50 lectures in it.

When a user clicks on a lecture, an excel file is created and a pre-installed add-in is created, in which anyone can edit it without signing in. Lecture will open that excel file, addin will then connect to the website to get information about the lecture.

The problem is, I do not know how to pass id lecture from my website -> excel file -> add in

I have reference through some functions like "Office.context.document.url", but still have not found the answer. May everyone help, solve this problem.

Comment: If the excel file is created on demand when the user opens the lecture, couldn't you pass the id through in a cell reference on a sheet? Another option I'd consider would be a RESTful method in the add-in to request the lecture content based upon the generated excel file.

Comment: Thanks Kade M, your idea is great! I am going to set name file excel contain id of lecture